# How to set parameters for workbench restart?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I hope to add -clean when restarting. At present, the way I can think of is to change the ini, and then change it back after restarting. This scheme feels stupid -.-"

Comment: This is indeed quite a cumbersome way, instead of simply using an argument on the command line: `eclipse -clean`.

Comment: I am so sad to see your reply .....There seems to be no better way, right ?

Comment: You could look at `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.actions.OpenWorkspaceAction` which is the "switch workspace" command to see how it builds up a command line using things like `Workbench.buildCommandLine`

Comment: Not sure about what you talking. If you meant programmatically restarting see greg-449's comment, but restarting with `-clean` is something a plugin should not do.

Comment: @howlger My English is very poor, using Google translation

Comment: @greg-449 , Will you write the answer or will I write it? Your suggestion is right

Comment: What I said is not an answer, I only suggested where to look. Also note that a lot of the code in those classes is 'internal' and is not supposed to be used by anything other than Eclipse itself.

Comment: ok,greg-449, I finished my research and wrote an answer to share with others

Comment: According to your suggestion, I wrote the test code, but it failed. There will be no parameter transfer during restart